# API suddenly stopped working, using regular web routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am working on an asp.net project and suddenly, seemingly out of the blue, the API has stopped working specifically for routes that use the `/api/{controller}/{id}` route.

Using, for example `/api/Events?param1=x&param2=y` works fine. It's just when using the optional parameter `{id}` that it seems to fall back to the regular web route: `/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Here are the relevant configs:

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMaps();
    }
```

An example of one of the actions that isn't working:

```
    // GET: api/Events/5
    [HttpGet]
    public EventReadDTO Get(int id)
    {
        using (var session = DBSessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                return session.Query<Event>()
                    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(x => Mapper.Map<EventReadDTO>(x))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be worthwhile for anyone using Telerik Reporting.

It seems that the line placed in `Global.asax` by the telerik reporting "wizard" causes a route to be registered that interferes with the default route created by ASP.NET MVC API.

The offending line is:

```
Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

In order to solve my problem, I move the line from the *top* of `Global.asax` to just after the last route configuration takes place:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {            
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMaps();
    }
```

This has solved the problem!